# Is it possible to create ArgoCD Account (Not a Group) for the users to only have read & execute permissions for a specific Project?

Tags: devops, argocd, argo, gitops

When looked at the documentation, I see it can be achieved for a group rather than an Account/User level: Projects - Argo CD - Declarative GitOps CD for Kubernetes (argo-cd.readthedocs.io)

Is there a way to create a single or multiple account for read & execute for a user within a specific Project level?

Comment: Like a local user account? Yep, you just use the username instead of group name when defining RBAC.